# Implicit Ordering in Bernoulli Distributions?

Tags: random-variable, binomial-distribution, categorical-encoding, bernoulli-distribution

Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable with success parameter $p$
As we usually consider the support as $\{0, 1\}$, we write $P(X = 1) = p$ and $P(X = 0) = 1-p$
This $0,1$-encoding seems to induce an ordering on the set of possible outcomes since $1 > 0$
Considering this, won't it be better to encode the outcomes as one-hot vectors $[0, 1]^T$ and $[1, 0]^T$, i.e., considering the support as $\{[0, 1]^T, [1, 0]^T\}$?

Comment: Why would you encode an outcome that way?  Note that the vectors you construct that way add up to $1$ all the time... therefore, knowing that the second element is $1-$ the first element all the time, there's no information gained by actually storing the second element.

Comment: @jbowman encoding that way doesn't impose any ordering on the encoded states. I know they add to $1$ and there's no information gained, but in most of machine learning we still use some redundant information (example: using $n$ weight vectors for each class in multi-class logistic regression, even when we could achieve the same thing using $n-1$ weight vectors)

Comment: There isn't any ordering in the states imposed by $\{0,1\}$ either; that's just imposed because we are used to thinking of $1 > 0$, but it's not actually implicit in the Bernoulli outcomes, or, more precisely, in the sample space.  You are, mentally, borrowing the ordering from a different sample space, e.g., the nonnegative integers, but it isn't actually an ordering that is part of the minimal Bernoulli probability space.  If you prefer, label them $H$ and $T$, as many, many word problems involving coin flipping do; everything works the same.

Comment: "Better" and "encode" for what purpose?  Certainly not for theoretical or conceptual reasons!

Comment: @jbowman but while computing $E[X]$ we do take $0, 1$ in the numerical sense right?

Comment: 1. The definitions of the $+$ and $*$ operators do not require the existence of the $>$ operator, and 2. The interpretation of $E[X]$ also doesn't require the existence of the $>$ operator.  One (frequentist) definition in the Bernoulli case would be, roughly, "what fraction of the time does the underlying event encoded by the symbol $1$ occur."

Comment: @jbowman then why is this not used for the case when we have more than $2$ classes? There we use one-hot encoding

Comment: You are confusing encoding with the underlying sample space to some extent, it seems to me.  With a 3 class situation, the sample space can be described, for example, as $\{A,B,C\}$, choose one.   There is no ordering there, consequently, there is no ordering in the encoding $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ which is the range of the typical map from the domain (sample space) to something convenient for calculations purposes.  You have to start with the sample space and realize that the numbers that you use are just the range of a map and borrow their properties from the sample space.

Comment: @jbowman for $\{A, B, C\}$, why can't we use $\{0, 1, 2\}$, using the same reasoning for $\{0, 1\}$ for Bernoulli

Comment: Certainly we can, but there's no implicit ordering or arithmetical operations in the multivariate Bernoulli sample space.   It's just symbols, you could use $\{*, ?, \% \}$ as well.

Comment: @jbowman thanks, it makes sense now. The confusion resulted from various sources (eg. [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)) claiming that $\{0,1,2\}$ imposes an ordering while one-hot doesn't.

Comment: Ah, yes, if whatever software you are using treats $\{0,1,2\}$ as numbers, then you are stuck with the consequences of that, including the ordering.  That clarifies the source of the issue for me too.   The one-hot encoding, as you observe, avoids this problem.  What we must do for computers is sometimes not the same as what we prefer to do in the math!

Comment: @jbowman in a software that treats $\{0, 1\}$ like integers, is it justified to use the $\{0,1\}$ encoding for a Bernoulli outcome? Because I've seen it being used almost everywhere

Comment: Oh, sure, that's just because $p^0$ and $p^1$ are defined mathematical functions, saves you the effort of defining $p^A$ and $p^B$ for example.  That's basically why we map the underlying sample space $\omega \in \Omega$ to $\{0,1\}$ in the first place.

Comment: @jbowman but you said that if a software treats them as numbers, then we're stuck with the consequences of that, including the ordering?

Comment: Just because the computer language has an operator $>$ that applies to $0$ and $1$ doesn't mean it's relevant for the Bernoulli sample space.   It also has $>$ implemented for 'a' and *, but that doesn't mean 'a' and * are numbers in the mathematical sense, even if they are sometimes interpreted as such in a computer sense.  ('a' > *. in case you're wondering.)

Comment: @jbowman so then we *can* use $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ for $4$ classes even in software?

Comment: That depends on the software.

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding will not solve any problems (whether theoretical or practical). Any results you get from an analysis using encoding as, say (*yes=1*, *no=0*) can be translated to the encoding (*yes=0*, *no=1*) without any loss or change in interpretation. This is called *invariance*.

The ordering $0 < 1$ simply do not play any role. See also the comments to the question.